# How to make a world map with clickable countries in AMcharts?

Tags: amcharts

Google maps is a bit of a nightmare in terms of getting GEOjson polygons for every country on a map, making them clickable, etc.

I came across AMcharts and it looks like a dream come true.  Is there a way in AMcharts to make a world map that allows you to:

•select multiple countries at once, 
•have click events for each country,
•displays the country's text on the map?

EDIT:  I am using Angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

> have click events for each country

You can use [listeners](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#listeners) in the configuration object to bind an event while using Angular. Then use [clickMapObject](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#clickMapObject) event to capture the click on a country.

You can get the map object from the event.

```
"listeners": [{
    "event": "clickMapObject",
    "method": function(e) {
        var mapObject = e.mapObject;
    }
}]
```

> select multiple countries at once

You can implement the multi-selection using the event above. Check the example here:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/864a70d0dc7140cb09ca507229166a11

> displays the country's text on the map?

The country name is displayed on the tooltip. I recommend to use that instead of having the names displayed on the map, as many of them would overlap.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Works great.  Is it necessary to include everything in the codepen in ngOnInit?  Seems like the country array would not be globally accessible if that's the case.